# Can an app setup with HTTP requests, receive json sent via HTTPS?

Tags: android, .htaccess

I've had a prototype native Android app sitting on my phone for ages, and use it to demo something to people; it's worked 100's times. The app grabs data from a JSON file on a public server and renders it on a map, nothing special.

Now I have an issue, the data isn't loading anymore!

The server is still running, and I can access the JSON file directly in a web browser, it works fine.

All else is the same except recently I re-configured the server to forward all HTTP traffic to HTTPS, using htaccess rules. This was for another project on the server and same domain.

Would this be the likely culprit? Will an Android app, with hardcoded requests to HTTP urls, have problems it's sent a response as HTTPS ?

I would have traced this on my own... however... I LOST THE SOURCE CODE for the app... something I realized months ago and knew some day it would be a problem.

This is the particular htaccess rule that forwards all HTTP traffic to HTTPS.

Can an exception be made for a particular .json file in the root (mywebsite.com/data.json)?

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer...

The http-to-https forwarding *was* the culprit.

I put an exception for my app's data.json (to keep it as HTTP), now the Android app works as usual.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/data.json [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to make another android application for testing and try to load the JSON using HTTP protocol and if that fails, using HTTPS protocol. Also yes, forcing all http -> https may cause issues (although it may seem normal in web browser) . If HTTP fails, just replace all HTTPURLConnection with HTTPSURLConeection and print the String result.

```
try {

            String result = "";

            URL url = new URL(YOUR_URL);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int i = reader.read();

            while(i != -1){

                result += (char) i;
                i = reader.read();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```